# Can a website block a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to block Chrome Extensions from running on particular websites?

Say I have a website [www.foo.com](http://www.foo.com), is it possible for me to block Chrome Extensions (in particular, content scripts) from working on my website, or stop them from accessing the DOM?

Comment: If this were possible, ads could disable ad-blockers and render them useless.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer: It would depend on the mechanism, but it's a definite issue.

Comment: I am not sure, but this does not seem technically possible. Since there is no way for your website to command the browser to stop using certain extensions or third party scripts, before it actually loads your website.

Comment: @GEMI: It would be totally possible for Chrome to provide a meta tag for this, for most extensions anyway.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder while theoretically possible I see no real drive for Google to do this, because it would render it's flourishing extensions market useless.

Comment: As mentioned, there is no general solution for blocking an extension. However, if you want to block/reverse an outcome of content script being injected to your page by a specific extension, then you should be able to do so. Say, some extension is injecting toolbar to your page - you should be able to remove with js or even css. If some content script is hiding your adds, just check, after couple of seconds, if these are visible and, if not, reload them.

Comment: User scripts also brake easily if you change ids and so on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***For the short Answer to the question goto the 4th Edit:***

You need to know the `extensionId` from the Extension you want to block, so that it works.

Here is a Testsite from the Prove of Concept
[Testsite](http://koto.github.io/blog-kotowicz-net-examples/chrome-addons/enumerate.html)

and here is the information behind the Solution:
[Intro to Chrome addons hacking: fingerprinting](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2012/02/intro-to-chrome-addons-hacking.html)

Now that you know what Extensions are Running you can, redirect/block/...

I hope it helps.

**Edit:**

Tested with (Chrome Version 27.0.1453.94) on Windows XP

**Edit 2:**

This technique will only work if:

1. You know the extensionid :)
2. **IMPORTANT!** at least one Ressource(like the manifest.json, some image, script, ...)
   is set as "web_accessible_resources" (in the manifest) OR the
   extension still uses a manifest version 1 and has no "web_accessible_resources" set. (Ressource from chrome dev site [Link](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources))

**Edit 3:**

Case Extension: ***JSONView***

You could detect the extension with this code(only example code):

```
<script src="chrome-extension://chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc/error.gif" onerror="console.info('Extension Not Found')" onload="console.info('Extension Found')"></script>
<!-- since the the file error.gif is allowed in the manifest "web_accessible_resources" (any other file mentioned there would also be fine) -->
<!-- the block code should come in the onload of the script tag -->
<!-- tested with Chrome 27+ WinXp -->
```

**Some Context:**
The JSONView Extension has a version 2 Manifest:

```
...
"manifest_version": 2, 
"name": "JSONView",
...
```

so by default you cannot access the manifest file as mentioned in the "Prove of Concept" above.

**BUT** it uses the **"web_accessible_resources"** attribute in the Manifest, which allows websites to access files from the Extension.

```
...
"web_accessible_resources": [ "jsonview.css", "jsonview-core.css", "content_error.css", "options.png", "close_icon.gif", "error.gif" ]
...
```

So now you can call any of this files from your webpage.

example:

```
chrome-extension://chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc/error.gif
chrome-extension://chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc/jsonview.css
...
```

And with this url in an Image/Script/.. -Tag you can know if the extension is there, if the onload Event fires.

P.s.: i only tested this with Chrome Version 27.0.1453.94) on Windows XP, in other Versions it might not work. (see comment from T.J. Crowder)

P.P.s.: For More Details check the Chrome Developer Ressources. Here is the Link to the Extension on the Chrome Ressource Page ["Finger printing" Stuff](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources))

**Edit 4:**

I don't think it can be blocked per se, but if you can detect the extension as mentioned above you could:

- redirect away from your Page
- or Popup a message(every few seconds) saying, "disable the extension for this Site"
- or you could check the Extension code to see if you maybe could "break" or hinder its functionality.
- or you could use some Code like in the answer of **BeardFist**

Comment: I don't believe that works anymore, Google patched the bug. Similarly, the mechanism in [his other article](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2012/02/intro-to-chrome-addons-hacking.html) about detecting specific extensions no longer works, either. For instance, [this test page](http://jsbin.com/abeyox/1) (source: http://jsbin.com/abeyox/1/edit) attempts to detect the Speed Dial extension. But while I have Speed Dial installed and enabled, it fails to detect it, because (as we can see in the Network tab) Chrome now prevents the script tag trick from working.

Comment: I tried the test page (Chrome Version 27.0.1453.94) extensions were listed. I just can say i tested it with my browser. Did you follow the link in my answer? were extensions listed?  please share the info so that i can refine my knowledge. THX

Comment: @ winner_joiner: Yes, I did follow the links. No, no extensions were listed (and I do have some installed). Chrome Version 26.0.1410.63 on Linux.

Comment: I went to the test page and it didn't lest any of my extensions. So as things stand at the moment, it seems websites can't stop Chrome extensions?

Comment: The Test Site only looks for extensions listed in the file [json-file](http://koto.github.io/blog-kotowicz-net-examples/chrome-addons/addons.json) of 5 of my extensions, only 2 are marked found. If you have the ID of the extension you want to block try the code from T.J. Crowder [link](http://jsbin.com/abeyox/1/edit) and enter your ID. I Could be that the extensions you use are not in the json-file.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder thank for the input, without it i would have found the reason why some extensions were found and others not.

Comment: @winner_joiner: But again, that code doesn't work (at this end), Chrome blocks the script load.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, if the code doesnt work in general for the Linux based Clients i can't say, but the Info mentioned in my second **Edit 2** works at least for window xp. (ex.: the extension yslow, is always shows through the code)

Comment: I've just tried the T.J Crowder link with the IDs of some extensions I am using and they are not being detected. I'm using Chrome version 27.

Comment: @sonicboom please checkout muy last Edit (**Edit 2**), may be the extension you want to block doesnt match the critira. Which Extension are you trying to block.

Comment: I am trying to detect JSONView which has the extension ID - chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc - if the extension itself has to have a flag like 'web_accessible_resources' set then it seems that extensions that don't have that flag set can't be detected by any currently available method?

Comment: @sonicboom i edited my answer. Now it states how you can detect for your specific extension. I hope the solves your Question.

Comment: OK, I see now how it can be detected, cheers. Do you know if it can be blocked, once it has been detected?

Comment: I dont think it can be blocked per se, but you could redirect away from your Page or Popup a message(every few seconds) saying, "disable the control for this Site" or you could check the Extension code to see if you maybe could "break" or hinder its functionality. Other options i wouldn't know.

Answer (score 23):

Since the other answer didn't really answer anything about actually stopping an extension, I thought I would add my own two cents. Using the method in the other answer, you can *sometimes* detect if a particular extension is installed and react accordingly, but this requires you to test for a particular ID string and file for that particular extension. I am sure that we can all agree that this isn't a very encompassing solution.

There are many things about extensions that you cannot stop from within your site, such as the `chrome.webRequest` api that adblock makes use of. There is nothing you can do to interfere directly with that sort of code, but there is plenty you can do on the DOM manipulation side.

`Content Scripts` operate in an `isolated world` meaning that they cannot see/interact with the javascript running on the site. They do, however, have complete access to the DOM and can do whatever they want to it. Conversely, your own javascript has the same access to that DOM. Taking advantage of that `isolated world` we can set up a `MutationObserver` to watch over the DOM and prevent any unwanted changes. Because of the `isolated world`, `content scripts` cannot disable or turn off our observer while our own javascript can do so freely.

Here is an example of a `MutationObserver` that locks down the DOM with a little `jQuery` mixed in because I am lazy.

```
var config= {childList: true,
             attributes: true,
             characterData: true, 
             subtree: true, 
             attributeOldValue: true, 
             characterDataOldValue: true};
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
    switch(mutation.type){
      case "attributes":
        observer.disconnect();
        if(mutation.attributeName == "class")
         mutation.target.className = mutation.oldValue;
        else if(mutation.attributeName=="id"||mutation.attributeName=="title")
         mutation.target[mutation.attributeName] = mutation.oldValue;
        else if(mutation.attributeName == "style")
          mutation.target.style.cssText = mutation.oldValue;
        observer.observe(document,config);
        break;
      case "characterData":
        observer.disconnect();
        mutation.target.data = mutation.oldValue;
        observer.observe(document,config);
        break;
      case "childList":
        observer.disconnect();
        if(mutation.addedNodes.length > 0)
          $(mutation.addedNodes[0]).remove();
        if(mutation.removedNodes.length > 0){
          if(mutation.nextSibling)
            $(mutation.removedNodes[0]).insertBefore(mutation.nextSibling);
          else if(mutation.previousSibling)
            $(mutation.removedNodes[0]).insertAfter(mutation.previousSibling);
          else
            $(mutation.removedNodes[0]).appendTo(mutation.target);
        }
        observer.observe(document,config);
        break;
    }
  });
});

$(function(){
  observer.observe(document,config);
});
```

Throwing it into a chrome extension with a simple manifest such as:

```
{
  "name": "DOM Polymerase",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "tabs","<all_urls>"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://example.iana.org/*"],
    "js": ["jquery-1.8.3.min.js","polymerase.js"]
  }]
}
```

And navigating to http://example.iana.org/ will show that external manipulation of the DOM (except for some attributes, I didn't code them all in there) is no longer possible. Of course, in this case internal manipulation is also denied, but if the code was in the site instead of an extension, it would be a different story. While this doesn't disable extensions completely, it should at least preserve your DOM.

Comment: Yes you are right i missed the "blocking-part" of the question, i only answered and mentioned a solution in a comment(i will copy it into the answer). I any case nice code, i will try it in a spare moment. THX for the input

Comment: +1 nice Code-Solution for detecting and preventing change in the DOM

Comment: While this is a nice concept, the reality is that the extension can either just prevent your script from being able to create the `MutationObserver`, or interpose itself between your observer and what's actually reported in order to prevent it's changes from being reported to your observer. Thus, yes, this will affect what a naive extension is able to do, but the extension can easily be written to prevent this from working.

Comment: @Makyen do you have a proof-of-concept for such an extension? I use mutationobservers in extensions, I wasn't aware there were ways around them

Comment: @MrMesees The extension can choose to run prior to anything from the webpage existing. That means it can override `MutationObserver` (or almost anything else) prior to the page calling `new MutationObserver`. Thus, what the page sets up as a "`MutationObserver`" can be something that the extension controls wrt. all data going to the page script's observer. In such case, the extension could do something as simple as never calling the observer's function, or the more complex task of filtering out all the changes made by the extension from those reported to the page's observer.

Comment: Interesting. I'd still love to see a code example, but sure it sounds like I've some reading to do. Interestingly I've heard chrome is phasing out extensions

Comment: @MrMesees on https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time it says that for `document_start` Scripts are injected after any files from css, but before any other DOM is constructed **or any other script is run**. I tried to place script even before html tag and extension with `document_start` was still winning.

Comment: I have to correct my previous comment. What @BeardFist says is also true:

`Content Scripts operate in an isolated world meaning that they cannot see/interact with the javascript running on the site.`

I tested that by trying to replace MutationObserver in extension that is set to run at `document_start` and it didn't change the one on the page. So MutationObserver solution definitely might have a chance.