# How can I force browser extensions/plugins to be inactive inside in my web app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am building a web application and they might be some sensitive information inside for my users. I see that some of the extensions I use in my browsers load code inside the web page... Is there a way to stop a browser like Chrome or Firefox or any other from being able to see or load anything in my web application HTML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect and/or block browser extensions that mess up my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404857/how-to-detect-and-or-block-browser-extensions-that-mess-up-my-website), and [Blocking Chrome Extensions from running on my site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264947/blocking-chrome-extensions-from-running-on-my-site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

I doubt the web application you're building will have information more sensitive than online banking sites, which don't prohibit extensions. The onus in this case is on the user (helped out by the browser and its extensions store) to not install malware.