# Is there a way to track mobile Chrome Extension installs?

Tags: mobile, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to track the install origin of my *Chrome Extension* in mobile devices.

I have different pages on mobile that lead to my extension page on *Chrome*. Users install the extension on mobile, and need to enable it on desktop.

Is there any way to know that a user installed the extension on mobile coming from a specific page?

Example flow:

1. User visits Page A on mobile, and clicks on "Get the extension"
2. User is redirected to the Chrome Web Store and installs the extension
3. The user enables the extension on desktop

How can I know that the origin is Page A?

Comment: Have you read [this SO post (Possibility for a website to track the user's chrome extensions, or their behaviour?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392357/possibility-for-a-website-to-track-the-users-chrome-extensions-or-their-behavi)?

Comment: Yep, I'm looking for a way to track the install source through mobile. My extension asks the user permission to track other things upon install on desktop.