# Flutter web has wrong colors in browser on Android with dark theme

Tags: android, flutter, opera, flutter-web

Opera Touch browser on Android is applying dark theme styling on websites created with Flutter, for devices with dark theme enabled.

Seems like all `Text` widgets are changed, e.g. from black to white, but backgrounds for widgets like `Container` are not always changed. This makes the webpage unreadable.

Is there a way to disable this in Flutter, like not let browsers apply their own theme?

I tried to force light theme, but that didn't help.

```
MaterialApp(
  title: webpageTitle,
  themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
  darkTheme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light)
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about opera propietary black theme "extension", but i saw some source code of some of the chrome extensions that i use, and in general what they do is either apply a global ".invert", or loop the whole webpage elements and changing the css/aplying invert in a selective way.

Since flutter doesn't have control about that behaviour, there is no way.. at least no in dart.

You could either apply a dark theme in your app, and set it as default. That might be the easy way.

You could also reverse engineer the script that opera executes , and fight it with your own javascript by disabling variables or overriding functions and the script would fail changing your app colors.

You can include javascript directly in your web app with [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/import_js_library).

I would use the first option, since most extensions fail to provide a nice dark theme, it's best if you implement it yourself. Or even use javascript to check variables that the script uses and if they exist  you call your app from javascript to enable the dark theme//show the user a warning that the app won't work well with that extension.

This is gonna be a recurring problem with flutter web apps in the future. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16786937/10205629) , altought that applies only to chrome extensions , maybe one day there will be a antidark script similar to antiadblock

Comment: Thanks for answer, it gives me some valuable info. Although the question is about Opera Touch on Android, so it's not the extension that inverts the colors, it's default browser behavior AFAIK. I'm not also sure making dark theme the default would solve that issue - the browser will probably revert the colors, so the page will be almost white. Right now I don't really see a good solution here

Answer (score 0):

Super late to the party, but what helped me was to render the app with canvaskit. html rendering must fall under the issue the previous commenter mentioned, of the browser going through and changing the CSS. Where canvaskit just paints the UI. Although then you have to deal with the wait, of the longer loading web app. But, Flutter Forward mentioned a 40% reduction of loading in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening while using the flutter web with html renderer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and this solve it. Also, I would like to mention that the build time was pretty much the same.

```
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit
```