# Is it possible to block IDM on my website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, download

I don't know how the chrome extensions work, but I just want to know. Is it possible to block Internet Download Manager to not run on my website.

For example if a user plays a video the IDM should not show a download option

Comment: If you deliver content to the user, then the user can copy/save it. Anything you do just makes it more difficult to copy/save. The questions are A) At what point is the difficulty level raised sufficiently for you to consider it acceptable? B) How much inconvenience are you willing to subject your users to? And, C) how much effort are you willing to expend to make it more difficult for them to copy/save?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blocking Chrome Extensions from running on my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264947/blocking-chrome-extensions-from-running-on-my-site)