# How to disable a specific extension programmatically?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How can I disable a specific extension programmatically from my own extension?

Comment: You can't. Helpful links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264947/blocking-chrome-extensions-from-running-on-my-site) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786186/can-a-website-block-a-chrome-extension/16803650).

Comment: What extention are you trying to disable? I don't think you can do this.

Comment: @shadoe2020 I try to disable ForceCop, because it affects my own extension.

Comment: In your own extension you can use [chrome.management API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management).

Answer (score 0):

"Extensity" chrome extensions programmatically disables extensions, so you can try giving a look at its code (if it is not obfuscated).