# How to ignore Chrome extensions html tags in my React.js App Hydration process?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-chrome-extension

There has been for a while React.js hydration issues due to Chrome extensions like Last Pass injecting html nodes at form inputs where words like “Email” or “Password” appear. This is obviously a problem while coding Next.js 14 apps, because this pop as errors every time.

[image: Hydration Error]

[image: Error description]

I haven’t found a solution for this other than removing the extensions. But this is not ideal since we cant assure all the users share the same non-extension scenario.

I also tried using "suppressHydrationWarning" every where with no effect. (Im still getting those hydration errors).

Any Help really appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blocking Chrome Extensions from running on my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264947/blocking-chrome-extensions-from-running-on-my-site)

Comment: I don't mind if the extension is not blocked, I just want to stop getting this error while I develop my next app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solutions from the Next.JS documentation? https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

You may need to look into CSR and move away from SSR  by disabling SSR on specific components. i.e.

```
const ComponentWithIssue = dynamic(() => import('../components/component-with-issue '), { ssr: false })`

....
return (
    <div>
      <ComponentWithIssue />
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: Why would I move away from SSR?, It's one of the main reasons to use Next.js.  And this happens to all form inputs.  Is your suggestion to avoid SSR on any component containing an input or form?  That doesn't sound very convenient.

Comment: Just going based on the documentation here. I did find this post of reddit that might help https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/10ralw8/new_to_nextjs_hydration_error_due_to_lastpass/